Bootstrap div inside column does not fill up without border
i am trying to place a div inside a col, but the div does not fill the entire col unless i place a border on the div.


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="row row-cols-3 g-2">
          <div class="col border border-danger">
              <div class="border bg-danger-subtle">
                  <p>hello</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col border border-danger">
              <div class="border bg-danger-subtle">
                  <p>hello</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col border border-danger">
              <div class="border bg-danger-subtle">
                  <p>hello</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col border border-danger">
              <div class="border bg-danger-subtle">
                  <p>hello</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col border border-danger">
              <div class="border bg-danger-subtle">
                  <p>hello</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col border border-danger">
              <div class="border bg-danger-subtle">
                  <p>hello</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col border border-danger">
              <div class="border bg-danger-subtle">
                  <p>hello</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col border border-danger">
              <div class="border bg-danger-subtle">
                  <p>hello</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col border border-danger">
              <div class="border bg-danger-subtle">
                  <p>hello</p>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>



but if i removed the border class on the div that is inside the col, the background will not fill up the entire height of the col.


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <div class="container text-center">
          <div class="row row-cols-3 g-2">
              <div class="col border border-danger">
                  <div class="bg-danger-subtle">
                      <p>hello</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col border border-danger">
                  <div class="bg-danger-subtle">
                      <p>hello</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col border border-danger">
                  <div class="bg-danger-subtle">
                      <p>hello</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col border border-danger">
                  <div class="bg-danger-subtle">
                      <p>hello</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col border border-danger">
                  <div class="bg-danger-subtle">
                      <p>hello</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col border border-danger">
                  <div class="bg-danger-subtle">
                      <p>hello</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col border border-danger">
                  <div class="bg-danger-subtle">
                      <p>hello</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col border border-danger">
                  <div class="bg-danger-subtle">
                      <p>hello</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col border border-danger">
                  <div class="bg-danger-subtle">
                      <p>hello</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
         </div>
    </body>
    </html>



is there any way i can fill the div background color without doing this hacky method of adding a border?

This appears to be a classic collapsing margins issue. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_box_model/Mastering_margin_collapsing (The margin-bottom of the p element in this case.)

thanks @C3roe, i just realized it was called margin collapsing in the first place. i added padding: 0.01px; instead and it worked without any visible border lines. though i still do not enjoy the hacky line atleast it does not give any visible side effect like having a border on the div.

There's a multitude of other way to fix this, which one works best for you, will depend on specifics. Applying overflow: hidden to .bg-danger-subtle would be one way, or to make them inline-block (and add width: 100%), or to make them be flex container themselves ...
